# Issues in Check box.Can any one solve the issue

Tags: java, android

Actually My Requirement is if we check any check box and click on button that check box name will show in another layout and rest of unchecked check boxs are disappear in next layout?What is the code for this type of issue

```
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.smallpizza);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.medpizza);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.largepizza);
    String txt1 = tv.getText().toString();
    String txt2 = tv1.getText().toString();
    String txt3 = tv2.getText().toString();
    int amount = 0;
    StringBuffer tot = new StringBuffer();
    tot.append("selected");
    if (small.isChecked())
    {
        tot.append("\nSmall pizza 280Rs");
        amount += 280;

    }
    if (medium.isChecked()) {
        tot.append("\nMedium 350 rs");
        amount += 350;
    }
    if (large.isChecked()) {
        tot.append("\nLarge pizza is 450 Rs");
        amount += 450;
    }
    tot.append("\nTotal:" + amount + "Rs");
    Toast.makeText(this, tot.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.vegquantity);
    tvv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tvv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tvv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    if (small.isChecked()) {

        tvv.setText(txt1);
    }
    if (medium.isChecked())
    {
        tvv1.setText(txt2);
    }
    if(large.isChecked()) {
        tvv2.setText(txt3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to code this already?

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started:

In the first layout listen for the checkbox state to become checked

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

In the next layout you can change the state of individual views

with 
     view.setVisibility( View.GONE| View.VISIBLE | View.INVISIBLE )

Where "view" is a reference to an individual checkbox.

Comment: can u show the programme pls?.actually check boxes are checked but unchecked check boxes are  does not disappear in next layout

Comment: Nope, not going to write if for you. You can listen for checkbox changes (first link). Then you need to update the visibility states on your second layout based on changes to those states. If you are changing activities you need to store the information somewhere and use it in the second layout.